# It ok for AJAX to take place over non-SSL?

Tags: .net, php, javascript, ajax

Say I have an https page can I make ajax calls to non SSL without getting warnings in browsers?

I want to do it for non sensitive data so its faster

Comment: HTTP isn't significantly faster than HTTPS.

Comment: Our database are slow and we are trying to tweak everything

Comment: No point tweaking the things that are fast already. Tweak the things that are slow. If you have slow databases then that's probably the place to start.

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't as this violates the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: "Domains, ports and protocols must match." (Just for those who didn't want to click.)